# LateInitializationError cannot understand why

Tags: android, ios, flutter, camera

I am building an app in flutter, and I am trying to open the camera for preview. I keep getting the error `LateInitializationError: Field _cameraController` I do not see why it's happening. my code is fairly small and I do not see why it's complaining.

```
late List<CameraDescription> cameras;

class AddPostPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddPostPage({super.key});

  @override
  _AddPostPageState createState() => _AddPostPageState();
}

class _AddPostPageState extends State<AddPostPage> {
  late CameraController _cameraController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    availableCameras().then((value) {
      cameras = value;
      if (cameras.isEmpty) {}
      _initCameraController(cameras[0]).then((void v) {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Future _initCameraController(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    await _cameraController.dispose();
    _cameraController =
        CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.high);

    _cameraController.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
    try {
      await _cameraController.initialize();
    } on Exception catch (exception) {
      print(exception);
    }

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, SizingInformation sizingInformation) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: double.infinity,
              child: CameraPreview(_cameraController),
            )
          ],
        ));
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cameraController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

It's happening at runtime when pressing on the button to access the camera in my app. I am using a iOS simulator

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to use `late` variables when they are not initialized yet. There is 3 places in your code where that might be the case:

```
await _cameraController.dispose();

...

child: CameraPreview(_cameraController),

...

_cameraController.dispose();
```

It would be better to make it nullable instead of late so change

```
late CameraController _cameraController;
```

to

```
CameraController? _cameraController;
```

Then you can change the usages to

```
await _cameraController?.dispose();

...

child: _cameraController == null ? CircularProgressIndicator() : CameraPreview(_cameraController!),

...

_cameraController?.dispose();
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

may be you try to check if the `_cameraController.value.isInitialized` before loading camerapreview

```
@override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, SizingInformation sizingInformation) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: double.infinity,
              child:  (_cameraController!=null&&_cameraController.value.isInitialized)? 
                     CameraPreview(_cameraController):
                     Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                      ),),
          ],
        ));
      },
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `_cameraController` isn't initialized when you are loading the `CameraPreview` is the likely culprit. I'd change `_cameraController` to a nullable instead.

In `build` do if `_cameraController == null` return an indicator or another widget, e.g. `Text('Loading ...`)`

Then once the _cameraController is set in SetState it will rebuild, not be null and should load.

Answer (score 0):

```
late List<CameraDescription> cameras;

class AddPostPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddPostPage({super.key});

  @override
  _AddPostPageState createState() => _AddPostPageState();
}

class _AddPostPageState extends State<AddPostPage> {
  final  CameraController? _cameraController; //Make change on this line//

  @override
  void initState() {
    availableCameras().then((value) {
      cameras = value;
      if (cameras.isEmpty) {}
      _initCameraController(cameras[0]).then((void v) {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Future _initCameraController(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    await _cameraController.dispose();
    _cameraController =
        CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.high);

    _cameraController.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
    try {
      await _cameraController.initialize();
    } on Exception catch (exception) {
      print(exception);
    }

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, SizingInformation sizingInformation) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: double.infinity,
              child: CameraPreview(_cameraController),
            )
          ],
        ));
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cameraController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```